# How to make maven changelog plugin generate both, a changelog.html and a changelog.xml

Tags: maven-3, file-type, changelog

Version: **Apache Maven 3.0.5**

I succesfully generated a changelog.xml via the maven site plugin and the command `mvn site`. Site plugin content of the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-beta-2</version>
    <configuration>
      <reportPlugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
      </reportPlugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now I require a changelog.html as well, I could not find any information on how to configurate my pom.xml to generate a html version of the changlog.

Comment: An alternative would be using this plugin and add several executions: https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You should move the plugin to the reporting section of your pom.xml.

To generate the reports you've to add the below to the configuration of the changelog plugin for the changelog and the dev-activity if you want it. There's also a file-activity report.

```
  <reportSets>
    <reportSet>
      <reports>
        <report>changelog</report>
        <report>dev-activity</report>
    </reports>
  </reportSet>
```

The plugin page has samples of these reports: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changelog-plugin/changelog.html